# How come nested loop runs faster than the single loop?

Tags: python, runtime, nested-loops

I was comparing the runtime of different approaches for a problem which required returning indices (as a list) of two numbers that adds up to a target number, and am baffled by the results obtained. Approach -1 had an approximated runtime of 344 ms while approach - 2 resulted with a runtime of 682 ms (when submitted
[at LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/description/)). I was under the pretense that the nested loop was far inferior to a singly ran loop. Was this observation a result of list with two numbers lying near to the starting point of the list? Even if that was the case, how come nested loop is efficient?

```
# Approach - 1
for index1, num1 in enumerate(nums):           
        num2 = target - num1
        if num2 in nums[index1 + 1:]:
            if nums.index(num2) != index1:
                return [index1, nums.index(num2)]
            else:
                return [index1, nums[index1 + 1:].index(num2) + index1 + 1]


# Approach - 2
for i in range(len(nums)):
        var = target - nums[i]
        a = nums.pop(i)
        try:
            index2 = nums.index(var) + 1
        except:
            nums.insert(i, a)
            continue
        return [i, index2]
```

Comment: Where's the nested loop?

Comment: With approach 2, you are constantly removing and adding back items in the list. I am surprised it is not an order of magnitude slower than approach 1.

Comment: What's the test case?

Comment: @JonSG Why would it be that much slower? I'm rather surprised it's even twice as slow.

Comment: @KellyBundy I've not timed it, but my gut tells me that inserting an item into a list at a given index could be comparatively expensive.

Comment: @KellyBundy Actually, when I time it, I see version 1 as 30x faster than version 2.

Comment: @JonSG But that's pretty much just a memmove. Very fast. Approach 1 instead makes a slice copy, which is already more expensive since it additionally increases all the reference counts (and decreases them afterwards). And *both* approaches search for a value, which involves object comparisons, which is even slower.

Comment: @JonSG With what test case, and how did you measure? With `nums, target = list(range(6000)), -1` I get ~320 ms for approach 1 and ~550 ms for approach 2.

Comment: @KellyBundy `[random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(100)], 100` but I admit that was just a guess at what might be valid input.

Comment: @JonSG That's not even remotely anywhere near their ~500 ms. Likely you even find a pair in the first iteration already.

Comment: @matszwecja If am not wrong here, isn't checking whether an item belongs to a list also a loop?

Comment: @Atypicalnerd Not really. Well, at least we usually don't refer to it as such. More correct statement would be that time complexity of checking whether an item belongs to a list is O(n). The thing is, potentially, so is `.pop` time complexity - https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @JonSG Timing with your `[random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(100)], 100`, approach 2 seems to actually be *faster* than approach 1 for me. Again: how did you measure?

Comment: @Atypicalnerd Not sure how I made you get it, as I still don't know it myself. And what I said rather argues against the answer you accepted. And you still haven't told us the test case .

Comment: @KellyBundy my apologies for not mentioning the test case, here is the test case for the code nums = [2,7,11,15] and target = 9. I just started LeetCode and got this problem there. Also, the runtime I mentioned above was from there after submission. Forgive me, if I created confusion around here.

Comment: There is absolutely no way that that test case took that long, so that's irrelevant. LeetCode is unreliable. How many times did you submit each solution, and what were the individual times?

Comment: @KellyBundy I submitted 4 times with approach-2 and I got the following runtime: 682, 697, 706 and 699 ms

Comment: What times do you with approach 2 if you change it to use `nums.index(var, i)` (as I added to my answer now)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pop, insert, slicing, and searching (whether with `in` or `index`) all take linear time on average, so *both* approaches have a "nested loop". But searching is by far the slowest, as that involves comparing values, which is relatively expensive. And approach 1 on average searches in n/2 values (where n=len(nums)) while approach 2 always searches in n-1 values. So it's no wonder if approach 2 takes about twice as much time.

You can easily make approach 2 also search in only n/2 values, by using `nums.index(var, i) + 1` instead of `nums.index(var) + 1`. And then it might be faster than approach 1, since pop+insert are faster than slicing. (Of course you don't even need to pop/insert, could simply use `nums.index(var, i + 1)`.)

At LeetCode I submitted your approach 1 a few times, took ~350 ms each time. Approach 2 took ~700 ms each time. And approach 2 with the added `, i` in the `index` call took ~395 ms each time. So it's still a bit slower, which I guess is due to catching exceptions being [expensive](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#how-fast-are-exceptions).

Comment: Wow! I tried your suggestion and it now came down to about ~392 ms, I didn't knew pop and insert were really expensive. Thank you for shedding light and pointing to the right direction !!

Comment: @Atypicalnerd Well they need to shift all list elements after the pop/insertion point one position to the left or right. They're fairly fast for a linear time operation (much faster than a linear time Python code loop), but they're still linear time.

Comment: I removed the pop/insert expressions and instead opted for nums.index(var, i + 1). One thing still though, by doing this how will it search in only n/2 values? Aren't we just shifting our search start position by 1 to right? We've still got n - 1 searches to be made (assuming that the first number is at the beginning), or is it like an average case thing?

Comment: @Atypicalnerd Yes, that's why I said "on average" (well, only the first time when I said n/2. I didn't feel like repeating it when I said n/2 again, I think that's clear enough).

Answer (score 0):

Continually inserting and deleting (pop) from a list is going to be expensive. If you're looking for an efficient way to implement this (it's the classic 2-Sum problem) then:

```
def sumsum(nums, target):
    info = {}
    for i, v in enumerate(nums):
        r = info.get(target - v)
        if r is not None:
            return [r, i]
        info[v] = i
```

**EDIT: Added full test case for this answer and the two approaches from the original question**

```
from timeit import timeit
from random import randint, shuffle

# this is the most efficient 2-sum algorithm that I can think of
def func1(nums, target):
    info = {}
    for i, v in enumerate(nums):
        r = info.get(target - v)
        if r is not None:
            return [r, i]
        info[v] = i


# this is approach 1
def func2(nums, target):
    for index1, num1 in enumerate(nums):
        num2 = target - num1
        if num2 in nums[index1 + 1 :]:
            if nums.index(num2) != index1:
                return [index1, nums.index(num2)]
            else:
                return [index1, nums[index1 + 1 :].index(num2) + index1 + 1]

# this is approach 2
def func3(nums, target):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        var = target - nums[i]
        a = nums.pop(i)
        try:
            index2 = nums.index(var) + 1
        except:
            nums.insert(i, a)
            continue
        return [i, index2]

# the performance of each function will vary depending on where the 2 key values are in the input list
# therefore, I build a list starting with two values which, when summed, equal a target
# I then pseudo-randomly add numbers to the list ensuring that the two key values are not repeated
# then pseudo-randomly shuffle the 100 element list
N = 5
totals = [0.] * 3
funcs = func1, func2, func3

# run N tests accumulating the durations for each function
for _ in range(N):
    nums = [2, 3]
    target = sum(nums)

    nums += [randint(10, 1000) for _ in range(98)]

    shuffle(nums)

    for i, func in enumerate(funcs):
        totals[i] += timeit(lambda: func(nums, target), number=5_000)

# show the averages
for f, t in zip(funcs, totals):
    print(f.__name__, f"{t / N:.4f}")
```

**Output:**

```
func1 0.0350
func2 0.1899
func3 0.6292
```

Thus func1 is superior to func2 (approach 1) by a factor of ~5
func2 (approach 1) is superior to func3 (approach 2) by a factor of ~3

```
**Platform:**

Python 3.12.1
macOS 14.2.1
Apple Silicon M2
```

Comment: pop+insert is far faster than slicing, so I think this is just wrong.

Comment: [Demo](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZHPSgMxEMbxmqeYW5OaXQxFkAWfpJQltJMaaP6QzIIivoU3L73oQ_k0JpstVpzTZL7J9xtmPr7iCz0Ffz5_TmS6h--bd5OCA7IOwboYEkHEZMZ9mDxhAp1njbEDGsgnu8fM_eSyGBiUMCGB9Qd8VhJKWZUHYEkwacKlEX6DXZKqbNtHuAU17Bhct1VYDHG0PmOif8BKSdofkZ_QN3WRa2h4nP374sCt-MPsF0crQQvGakkC6XREKr9ONhNvxuquhBASOsVYhZoK3bYNyKvhdrCGTYNXi7os3pimTTbnMVlP3KxeeWvoSKwVbob7Xpk3cBlWEkw_jl47HEfRjrPc6HKrHw), pop+insert being ~6.5 times faster than slices.

Comment: @KellyBundy Why is Approach 2 so much slower than Approach 1

Comment: Didn't know yet but looked into it now and posted an answer.

Comment: Your benchmark repeats Jon's mistake, see their answer and my comment there

Comment: @KellyBundy What are you talking about? My solution (func1) doesn't modify the input list in any way. func2 and func3 are repetitions of OP's original code just for performance comparison purposes

Comment: As I said, the OP's approach 2 modifies the list, so calling it repeatedly with the same list is broken.

Comment: In your case, func3 pops the 2 or 3 in the first iteration, and then in the 4999 remaining iterations it has to search the entire list because there is no pair with the target sum anymore. So if you call it with `nums[:]`, it becomes much faster (despite the additional time for that copy).